# Splitting an IP Address Range, IP addresses stop after 210937 records

Tags: php, ip

I have a database of IP ranges and I am using the code below to split the range in to individual IP addresses.  This works fine until I get to 210937 records then the code stops spilitting the IP range and starts inserting 0.0.0.0.

I have tried removing some IP addresses but it still stops at the same point even though the IP address is different.

```
 for ($ip = ip2long($ip1); $ip<=ip2long($ip2); $ip++)
 {
 $lip = long2ip($ip);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Ok so here is the full code minus db connection.

```
  $query1 = "SELECT * FROM masteriplist";
  $result = mysql_query($query1);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 

   $ipe = $row['ip_end_range'];
   $ips = $row['ip_start_range'];

   $ip1 = "$ips";
   $ip2 = "$ipe";


   for ($ip = ip2long($ip1); $ip<=ip2long($ip2); $ip++)
    {
    $lip = long2ip($ip);


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_master (ip) VALUES ('$lip')") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

     }
     }
```

ok the debugging code returned the following

```
array(24) { 
  ["id"]=> string(2) "50" 
  ["ip_address"]=> string(12) "85.119.25.27"
  ["ip_start_range"]=> string(0) ""
  ["ip_end_range"]=> string(0) ""
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Class If that were the case, it wouldn't insert anything afterwards.

Comment: Hi I am taking ip addresses from a table start and end, each contanig a single ip address, the code is like this.  $ipe = $row['ip_end_range'];
$ips = $row['ip_start_range'];

$ip1 = "$ips";
$ip2 = "$ipe";

Comment: Yes after it stops inserting it carries on for thousands of records but just inserting 0.0.0.0.0

Comment: I think you need to post more code.

Comment: I'd like to see more code too. For one thing, I would use your ip2long functions outside of the loop.

Comment: Could you add some debugging in the code? `if ($lip == '0.0.0.0') { var_dump($row); exit; }`

Comment: Ok that returned the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're processing a single IP address instead of a range; dealing with both could be done with this:

```
if ($row['ip_start_range'] == '' || $row['ip_end_range'] == '') {
    $ip1 = $ip2 = $row['ip_address'];
} else {
    $ip1 = $row['ip_start_range'];
    $ip2 = $row['ip_end_range'];
}
```

Also, you could make it more efficient by moving the `ip2long` calls outside of the loop:

```
$start = ip2long($ip1);
$stop = ip2long($ip2);

for ($ip = $start; $ip <= $stop; $ip++) {
  // ...
}
```